# Yii TCPDF missing embed font in Corel Draw X6

Tags: php, pdf, yii, fonts, tcpdf

I'm using this extension in Yii:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tcpdf/

I would like to write to a pdf file with an external font, for example this:
http://www.1001fonts.com/open-sans-font.html

Here is my code:

```
    $pdf = Yii::createComponent('application.extensions.tcpdf.ETcPdf', 'P', 'cm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8');
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor("Some Body");
    $pdf->SetTitle("TCPDF Example 002");
    $pdf->SetSubject("TCPDF Tutorial");
    $pdf->SetKeywords("TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide");
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $fontRegular = $pdf->addTTFfont(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
    $pdf->SetFont($fontRegular, "", 30);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Example",1,1,'C');
    $pdf->Output("example_002.pdf", "I");
```

It works, I can read the pdf many programs, except Corel Draw 6X. When I'm opening the pdf it starts with a message of "missing fonts" and I can't replace them any other kind of fonts. Can anyone tell me how should I add the ttf font, or embed it into the pdf?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is for Corel Draw . You have to Install the font.

1)Download your ttf font from [here](http://www.1001fonts.com/search.html?search=ttf)

2)Extract it and copy the font to  `C:\Windows\Fonts`

3) Restart Corel Draw and make sure the new font is available by creating a text field and selecting the font.

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5NA-XDdVao)